# Independent Column Calculation

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

New to SQL Server (T-SQL) and I am not able to find an answer to this question by searching online.

I am trying to write a query that will give me a max date and a count of events since that date in another column. The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT 
    [EmployeeKey], MAX([EvaluationDateTime]) AS [LastFailDate]      
FROM 
    [DataWarehouse].[quality].[FactEvaluation_Current]
WHERE 
    EvaluationScoreTotal < 80.00
GROUP BY 
    [EmployeeKey];
```

I now need to add an additional column that will count all the events from the date returned as `LastFailDate` but I'm not sure where to add this into this query so that it won't be affected by the `WHERE` clause?

I think I need something like

```
SELECT 
    COUNT[EvaluationDateTime]
FROM
    [DataWarehouse].[quality].[FactEvaluation_Current]
WHERE 
    [EvaluationDateTime] > [LastFailDate]
```

Any help or direction of where I can find the answer to this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to ask a great question, and get the most help from other users, it needs to be [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This question is already Minimal and Complete, but missing the Verifiable example. Can you provide some sample data, and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I think below query gives what you want.

```
 SELECT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT [EmployeeKey], MAX([EvaluationDateTime]) as [LastFailDate],COUNT[EvaluationDateTime] as  [Count_LastFailDate]
    FROM [DataWarehouse].[quality].[FactEvaluation_Current]
    WHERE EvaluationScoreTotal < 80.00  
    GROUP BY [EmployeeKey]
    )CNT
    WHERE [EvaluationDateTime] > [LastFailDate];
```

But if you want more appropriate answer. Give DDL with sample data.

Comment: I get an "Invalid column name 'LastFailDate'." error. I think this is because LastFailDate is not a column which exist in my data It is created in the first column of the query? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my answer. Give sample data to give accurate answer.